# How do I get syntax highlighting when using HTML as source in Pelican?

Tags: pygments, pelican

I recently started using the pelican cms, and I prefer to write my articles in HTML, as opposed to rst or markdown. Thats's fine. Pelican lets me do that.

But I can't seem to find any way to specify the language for `<pre>` blocks so Pelican will run it through Pygments to generate syntax higlighting.

The documentation only specifies how to do this with markdown or rst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because pelican itself doesn't use Pygments directly. It's applied through `md` and `rst` processors. As for HTML contents, pelican doesn't do anything except extracting the metadata from it. It's probably easier to use something like [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).